# MS Access Extract all text between brackets to new query

Tags: regex, database, ms-access, vba

I have a multi-line string variable that holds a large data string. Some of that data is enclosed between square brackets.

Example data variable:

```
[text 123] 
text [text] 234 [blah] blah
some more [text 123]
```

I need to extract all the data between the square brackets into a query or table, so it would be something like this:

```
text 123
test
blah
text 123
```

Here is my VBA code below:

```
    Dim dataString As String
    dataString = "test [field 1] mroe text [field 2] etc"

    Dim searchStr As String
    Dim regExp As Object
    Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection
    Dim match As Variant

    searchStr = dataString
    Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regExp
        .pattern = "(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
    End With
    Set colregmatch = regExp.Execute(searchStr)
    If colregmatch.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each match In colregmatch
            MsgBox match.Value
            Debug.Print match.Value
        Next
    End If
    Set colregmatch = Nothing
    Set regExp = Nothing
```

UPDATE: I get a 5017 run time error when using this pattern. If I use "[([^]]+)]" as the pattern, it works but the brackets are not removed...

Comment: "I am trying to do something with regex" - always helps to show what you tried, and describe what happened when you ran your code.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work:

```
/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/gm
```

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVi5zV/1) of the regex in action.

**Regex Breakdown:**

- `(?<=\[)`: Positive lookbehind
- `\[`: matches the character **[** literally (case sensitive)
- `.*?`: matches any character (except for line terminators) lazily (as few as possible)
- `(?=\])`: Positive lookahead
- `\]`: matches the character **]** literally (case sensitive)
- `gm`: global and multi-line modifiers

Comment: This gives me a run time error 5017 "application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: You may have to tweak how the regex is presented in whatever software you are using. What is interpreting your regex?

Comment: I don't believe lookbehind is supported in VBscript.

Comment: What if you change your regex to `"\[(.*?)\]"` and then reference the data you need in your loop with `match.Submatches(0)`?